# get email and website from two different <div> with same name with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've managed to use `find_all` to get the two classes `"IdiaP Me sNsFa"` , but now I'm struggling to get the website and the email address.

```
contacts_container = s_restaurant.find_all(class_="IdiaP Me sNsFa")

for contact in contacts_container:
    print(contact["href"])
```

this gives an error.

[image]

**update:**
when I `print(contact.a)` of the first item in the array (with `class="YnKZo Ci Wc _S C FPPgD"`), the `href` (website) is not printed

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
contacts_container = s_restaurant.find_all(class_="IdiaP Me sNsFa")

for contact in contacts_container:
    a = contact.a
    if a and a.get('href'):
        print(a["href"])
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't work
`in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
           ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 'href'`

Comment: thanks. your updated answer retrieves the email only. please check my updated post. i've noticed that the `href` of the website is not printed

Comment: @peetman Could be the data is retrieved via Javascript so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. When you do `print(s_restaurant)` do you see the `href=` there under the right `class=`?

Comment: good question. no I don't see it